# Make button an image in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does anybody know how to make a button an image in jquery mobile that retains the button characteristics (such as shadowing on click)?

I currently am using the Jquery Mobile image button:

```
 <input type='image' src='img/facebook-login-button.png' id='login-with-facebook'/>
```

But it looks kind of awful. The look doesn't change when it's clicked, so it just looks stamped on the screen. I originally had a button tag but I couldn't figure out how to style it with an image.

Does anybody know any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

If you need lighter overlay:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/57/

#### HTML:

```
<a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
```

#### CSS:

```
.im-btn {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:url(http://indul.ccio.co/g5/84/v8/102034747777689280Uk0sEZQUc.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.im-btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.im-btn:active {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

## Solution 2

If you need darker overlay:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/58/

#### HTML:

```
<a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
```

#### CSS:

```
.im-btn {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:url(http://indul.ccio.co/g5/84/v8/102034747777689280Uk0sEZQUc.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.im-btn:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#444;
    opacity:0.4;
}

.im-btn:active > .overlay {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```